# using std::conditional to choose member type based on template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

Here is my program that attempts to use std::conditional to set the type of a member variable based on the value of an integer template parameter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

class cool{
public:
  cool(){ printf("Cool!\n");  }
};

class notcool{
public:
  notcool(){ printf("Not cool!\n");  }
};

template<int N>
class myclass{
public:
  typedef std::conditional<N==5,cool,notcool> thetype;
  thetype theinst;
};

int main(){
  printf("Testing\n");
  myclass<5> myc5;
  myclass<6> myc6;
  printf("Done testing\n");
  return 0; 
}
```

I would expect my program to give the following output:

> Testing
>
> Cool!
>
> Not cool!
>
> Done testing

Instead, the output is

> Testing
>
> Done testing

My compiler is GCC 4.9, and the way I compiled this program was using the command g++ test -std=c++11 -o test

Can anyone tell me why the program does not give the output I expect?

Comment: Those are constructors, they should be called automatically when the object myclass is instantiated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
typedef typename std::conditional<N==5,cool,notcool>::type thetype;
//      ^^^^^^^^                                    ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work. Can you explain what is the difference between this and the line in my code?

Comment: Shorter C++14 way: `typedef std::conditional_t<...> thetype;`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `using thetype = std::conditional_t<...>;`

Answer (score 6):

`thetype` is actually not `cool`, and also not `notcool`. But [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional).

Yes. `std::conditional` is a type, that's how most type traits are implemented. If you want to get the underlying type from the conditional, you need to access the underlying `type` member from `std::conditional`. That's also how most type traits are implemented: They all have a `type` member which can be used to access the actual type you want, and not the type trait type.

In C++14, you would use `std::conditional_t`, which is just a alias for the `type` member of `std::conditional`, but because you are using C++11, you need to access it explicitly:

```
typedef typename std::conditional<N == 5, cool, notcool>::type thetype;
```